# PC does not boot when booting

Tags: boot

Four months ago I bought a Dell computer with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS installed. A month later, i had to turn off the PC button because it didn't continue to install for a long time when i wanted to update it to 19.04 ubuntu. The computer made errors when it was reopened, but it was updated at 7:04 p.m. Then I updated at 7:10 p.m. I now have ubuntu 20.04 LTS installed on my computer on April 25.

My problem is when I turn on the PC, it doesn't boot directly. It falls into the grub directory by saying the wrong command. I'm getting a reboot again. When I do this 2-3 times, the initramfs package could not be opened and the ubuntu is installed by giving mouse error at 2. Even when I press escape, there's nothing wrong with the study, but how do I solve this boot thing, even though I received the bug that couldn't be booted from the grub in the leaking article. Of course, since it does not boot normally, I applied commands from the terminal, accompanied by articles I read online about how to solve the problem. Failed.

I printed the iso file of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on DVD. I tested it before you set it up, no problem. Ok, let me install the new one but there are movies and pdf comics i want to watch in the ext4 linux installed section 200 gbit as soon as possible. I said to narrow the ext4 Linux section with dVDs and gparted it, and transfer it to the new section, but when the gparted worked and locked it towards the end, there was no room.

In short, my computer opens when rebooted 3-4 times, but once I open it, I want it turned on. Because I installed Snap, it opened a worldwide mount directory for programs in the package. Only Ubuntu is installed on my computer. Harddisk 3 e divided.The first part efi, the second part is reserved for Microsoft 5 Gb, the third part ext4 Linux up to 870 Gb.

The last thing I want to ask is that when I want to install the computer again from usb or dvd Ubuntu, I should disable the Security Boot option on Bios. As far as I know, for these windows installations,

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Bu site sadece İngilizce soru - cevap sitesidir. Sorularınızı spesifik olarak tek tek (ayrı ayrı) ve İngilizce olarak sormanız gerekir. / This is an English only Q&A web site. Please ask your question(s) in a specific manner and one by one *in English*.

Answer (score 0):

Do a clean install of Ubuntu 20.04.

1. Download the 20.04 disk image (.iso) from the [official website](https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop).
2. Make a [bootable USB](https://www.howtogeek.com/191054/how-to-create-bootable-usb-drives-and-sd-cards-for-every-operating-system/) or disk from the Ubuntu disk image
3. Boot your computer from the bootable USB and follow on-screen prompts to do a clean reinstallation of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.